# Mean Estimation from 1 Sample that gives Mean and Standard Deviation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

The title didn't feel right to me either, but here is my problem: I am attempting to estimate the mean of lead concentration using a handheld x-ray gun, which takes a measurement at a point on the wall, and outputs a mean and standard deviation (example: mean=1.1mg/cm^2, sigma = 0.2). If the device takes several samples, it doesn't specify how many, so I can't use it for, say, a T distribution, unless I multiple samples of the same substrate, which kills the batteries and takes more time than I am given.

The product spec sheet states that it detects lead at 0.1 mg/cm^2 with 2 sigma confidence.

How can I interpret these results to determine the confidence intervals for a = 0.01 and 0.05, assuming a Normal distribution?

Comment: The spec sheet seems unhelpful, except possibly to let you know the lower limit of lead the device can detect.  You may or may not get a straightforward answer if you ontact the manufacturer to see whether several measurements are used to get a result such as mean 1.1mg${}^2$ and SD  0.2. If no useful answer, you could do multiple runs at a few spots to get some idea with what precision the SD is measured Then you might have a basis for making CIs for future single measurements.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, the $t$-distribution tends towards the normal distribution as the sample size increases. Therefore, if you are willing to assume that the underling distribution is normal -- which is a requirement for your $t$-distribution argument anyway -- you might also assume that the sample size is large enough, such that the normal and the $t$-distribution are very similar [my guess is that this is save to assume]. Hence, I would just use the 68-95-99.7% rule to obtain the confidence bounds of your measurements. Using your data above, I would state that you are 95% confident that the averaged lead concentration lies within the interval $\bar x \pm 2\sigma = (1.1 \pm 0.4)mg/cm^2$.

If you like to check this assumption, you stated the solution already. First take many measurements from the same sample. Then use the central limit theorem. If the assumption is correct we expect that approx. 68% of the $\pm 1 \sigma$ confidence intervals contain the grand sample average and approx. 95% of the $\pm 2 \sigma$ confidence intervals contain the grand sample average.